# Use Stunnel to connect wss to wsServer

Tags: ssl, websocket, stunnel

I am trying to use stunnel to turn a wss connection into a ws connection because [wsServer](https://github.com/Theldus/wsServer) doesn't support wss.  The server is running Ubuntu, and the client I'm using is Chrome, if it matters.

This is my `stunnel.conf` file

```
foreground = yes
debug = info
output = /var/log/stunnel.log

[wsServer]
cert = /etc/letsencrypt/live/myurl.com/fullchain.pem
key = /etc/letsencrypt/live/myurl.com/privkey.pem
accept = 0.0.0.0:8443
connect = 127.0.0.1:8080
```

I'm trying to connect to it with a javascript call:

```
const socket = new WebSocket('wss://myurl.com:8433');
```

But I consistantly get a connection error:

```
(index):13 WebSocket connection to 'wss://myurl.com:8433/' failed: (anonymous) @ (index):13
```

Here's what I've checked:

- That my port forwarding/system firewalls aren't eating the connection. If I kill stunnel and setup a regular socket listening on either port 8080 or 8433, I can connect to that socket from the client machine.
- wsServer  accepts non-encrypted traffic, if I instead connect with `ws://myurl.com:8080` it works fine
- wsServer accepts connections from localhost just fine, which I understand is necessary when stunnel is running on the same machine as the server
- Chrome accepts my cert when used for https pages under the same domain, so I don't think I have a cert signing error, but I don't know how to tell if the cert is related to the connection failing
- Stunnel does not print any errors when starting up
- Nothing gets printed to `/var/log/stunnel.log`, although the file was created after I added the output field to the .conf file

Any ideas about what else I can try? Is there some reason the cert that works for https wouldn't work with wss?

Do people recommend using ProxyPass through apache and avoiding stunnel altogether?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a solution, but a next troubleshooting step. Get yourself openssl and attempt to connect to 8443. This should spit back the certificate information and at least confirm stunnel is presenting the certificate.

```
openssl s_client -connect myurl.com:8443
```

It's been awhile since I configured stunnel, but IIRC you can't put a password on your key.

Comment: that's a good idea, I appreciate you telling me about that tool.  And it did lead me to the answer because it made me realize I made a silly typo. I am using 8443 in some places and 8433 in other places.  Changing the stunnel.conf to 8433 and now it's working.